# Alarm manager show notification every time when i open the app

Tags: kotlin, alarmmanager

I am using the requestj api to send and receive the data from server and setting up the alarm on time that i received from server and alarm calls two hours ago from received time but issue is that when alarm fire on exact time it also fire every time when api calls till that 2 hours didn't completed. Any one know how to prevent it?
**1.API code is here**

```
    fun getAllFriendsReminders(context: Context) {
        val getReminderHttpRequest = HttpRequest()
//        val myList = ArrayList<FriendsRemindersListModel>()
        getReminderHttpRequest.setOnResponseListener { getReminderListResponse ->

            Log.e("getReminders List", getReminderListResponse.code.toString())
            Log.e("getReminders List", getReminderListResponse.text)
            if (getReminderListResponse.code == HttpResponse.HTTP_OK) {
                Log.e("getReminders List", getReminderListResponse.code.toString())
                val jsonArray = getReminderListResponse.toJSONArray()

                getReminderListModel.clear()
                Log.e("list", jsonArray.length().toString())
                Log.e("list", jsonArray.toString())

                val loggedInUser = appGlobals.getValueString("loginUsername")

                for (i in 0 until jsonArray!!.length()) {

                    if (!onForeGround) {
                        progressBar!!.progress = i
                    }
                    Log.e("listi", i.toString())

                    val jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)

                    friendReminderText = jsonObject.getString("reminder")
                    friendReminderFromName = jsonObject.getString("reminder_from")
                    friendReminderToName = jsonObject.getString("reminder_to")
                    friendReminderDate = jsonObject.getString("date")
                    friendReminderStatus = jsonObject.getString("status")
                    friendReminderId = jsonObject.getString("id")

                    if (friendReminderFromName != loggedInUser) {
                        getReminderListModel.add(FriendsRemindersListModel(0, friendReminderId.toInt(),friendReminderText,
                            friendReminderDate, friendReminderFromName, friendReminderToName, friendReminderStatus))

                        //Received date time from server
                        val dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a")
//                        val dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy")
//                        val timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss a")

                        val instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(friendReminderDate.toLong())
                        val instant1 = Instant.ofEpochMilli(friendReminderDate.toLong() - (120 * 60 * 1000))
                        val date = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault())
                        val date1 = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant1, ZoneId.systemDefault())
//                        val exactDate = dateFormatter.format(date)
//                        val exactTime = timeFormatter.format(date)
                        val exactDateTime = dateTimeFormatter.format(date)

                        val alarmDate = Date(friendReminderDate.toLong())

                        //Current date time
                        val dates = Date()
                        val stringFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a")
                        val dateTimeTo = stringFormat.format(dates.time)

                        //Set Alarm

                        if (alarmDate.after(dates)) {
                            Log.d("D", dates.toString())
                            Log.d("AlarmDate", alarmDate.toString())
                            Log.e("2 hour ago", dateTimeFormatter.format(date1))
                            println(friendReminderDate.toLong() - (120 * 60 * 1000))
                            Log.e("Set", exactDateTime)

                            val alarmManager: AlarmManager = context.getSystemService(
                                AppCompatActivity.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
                            val alarmIntent = Intent(requireContext(), AlarmReceiver::class.java)
                            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0)

                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                Log.e("Alarm", "Alarm")
                                alarmManager.setAlarmClock(AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(friendReminderDate.toLong() - 120*60*1000,
                                    pendingIntent), pendingIntent)
                            } else {
                                Log.e("Alarm1", "${friendReminderDate.toLong() - (120 * 60 * 1000)}")
                                alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                    (friendReminderDate.toLong()) - 120 * 60 * 1000,
                                    pendingIntent)
                                Log.e("Alarm2", "Alarm")
                            }
                        }
//                        if (exactDateTime > dateTimeTo) {
//
//                        }
                    }
                }

                if (friendReminderFromName != loggedInUser) {

                    if (friendReminderId != "") {
                        reminder = FriendsRemindersListModel(0, friendReminderId.toInt(), friendReminderText, friendReminderDate,
                            friendReminderFromName, friendReminderToName, friendReminderStatus)
                    }
                }

                if (getReminderListModel.size.toString() > remindersListModel.size.toString()) {
                    Log.e("serverListSize", getReminderListModel.size.toString())
                    Log.e("dbListSize", remindersListModel.size.toString())
                    Log.e("JsonListSize", jsonArray.length().toString())

                    for (i in 0 until getReminderListModel.size - 1) {
                        Log.e("present", getReminderListModel[i].reminderId.toString())
                        var isPresent = false
                        for (j in 0 until remindersListModel.size - 1) {
                            Log.e("present", remindersListModel.toString())

                            if (remindersListModel.isNotEmpty()) {
                                if (getReminderListModel[i].reminderId == remindersListModel[i].reminderId) {
                                    isPresent = true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        Log.e("presenting", "${!isPresent}")

                        if (isPresent) {
                            remindersViewModel.addingReminder(reminder)

                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (getReminderListModel.size.toString() < remindersListModel.size.toString()) {
                    for (i in 0 until remindersListModel.size - 1) {
                        for (j in 0 until getReminderListModel.size - 1) {
//                        var isRemoved = false
//                        Log.e("i's", i.toString())
                            Log.e("i's", getReminderListModel.size.toString())
                            Log.e("i'ss", remindersListModel.size.toString())

                            if (remindersListModel.isNotEmpty()) {
                                Log.e("delete3", remindersListModel[i].reminderId.toString())
                                Log.e("delete3", remindersListModel[i].reminderText)
                                Log.e("delete4", getReminderListModel[j].reminderId.toString())
                                Log.e("delete4", getReminderListModel[j].reminderText)
                                if (remindersListModel[i].reminderId != getReminderListModel[i].reminderId ) {
                                    Log.e("delete2", remindersListModel[i].reminderId.toString())
                                    remindersViewModel.deleteReminder(remindersListModel[i].reminderId)
//                                    getReminderListAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(i)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

//                if (getReminderListModel.size.toString() != getRemindersDBList.size.toString()) {
//                    remindersViewModel.deleteReceivedReminders()
//                    remindersViewModel.addReminder(getReminderListModel)
//                }

                if (progressBar!= null) {
                    progressBar!!.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }
        }

        getReminderHttpRequest.setOnErrorListener {
            if (progressBar != null) {
                progressBar!!.visibility = View.GONE
            }
            Log.e("getReminders error", "$it")
            Log.e("Alarm1", "${friendReminderDate.toLong() - (120 * 60 * 1000)}")

        }
        val token = appGlobals.getValueString("userToken")
        val headers = HttpHeaders("Authorization", "Token $token")
        getReminderHttpRequest.get(AppGlobals.GET_REMINDERS_LIST_API, headers)
    }
```

**2. Alarm receiver class:**

```
class AlarmReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @SuppressLint("UnsafeProtectedBroadcastReceiver")
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

            showNotification(context!!, MessagingServiceFirebase.title, MessagingServiceFirebase.body)
        Log.e("Checking notify", "Notification")

//        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        Log.e("Checking ", "Notification")

//        ringTone(context)
    }

//    private fun ringTone(context: Context) {
//        val alert: Uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM)
//        val ringtone: Ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alert)
//
//        ringtone.play()
//        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
//    }

    fun showNotification(ctx: Context, title: String, message: String) {
        val notificationManager =
            ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channelId = "channel"
            val name: CharSequence = "channel"
            val description = "The channel"
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            val mChannel = NotificationChannel(channelId, name, importance)
            mChannel.description = description
            mChannel.enableLights(true)
            mChannel.lightColor = Color.RED
            mChannel.enableVibration(true)
            mChannel.vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400)
            mChannel.setShowBadge(false)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
        }
        val builder: NotificationCompat.Builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx, "channel")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_access_alarm_24)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
        val resultIntent = Intent(ctx, HomeActivity::class.java)
        val stackBuilder: TaskStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(ctx)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(HomeActivity::class.java)
        resultIntent.putExtra("NotifyTitle", title)
        resultIntent.putExtra("NotifyMessage", message)
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent)
        val resultPendingIntent: PendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
        builder.setAutoCancel(true)
        notificationManager.notify(12, builder.build())
    }

}
```

**3. Manifest code**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<receiver
            android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pull `date` from the JSON, and set an alarm for 2 hours before that? So if `date` is 6pm, you set an alarm for 4pm?

```
alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
    AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
    friendReminderDate.toLong()) - 120 * 60 * 1000, // date - 2hrs
    pendingIntent)
```

If it's 5pm right now, and you set an alarm for 4pm, [it will still set, and fire immediately](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#set(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)):

> **If the stated trigger time is in the past, the alarm will be triggered immediately**. If there is already an alarm for this Intent scheduled (with the equality of two intents being defined by `Intent#filterEquals`), then it will be removed and replaced by this one.

So if you only want to set the alarm if `now <= alarmTime`, and just skip it if `now > alarmTime`, you need to do that check before you set the alarm.

---

It looks like you're trying to do that:

```
if (alarmDate.after(dates)) {
```

but `alarmDate` is "date", not "date - 2hrs" (you're using 6pm instead of 4pm):

```
val alarmDate = Date(friendReminderDate.toLong())
```

So during that 2-hour period, you're always setting alarms that fire immediately. You need to use your actual alarm time instead:

```
// seriously, just do this calculation once and refer to the variable
val alarmTime = friendReminderDate.toLong() - (120 * 60 * 1000)
val alarmDate = Date(alarmTime)
```

You have a lot of date variables piling up in there, it's confusing and hard to tell what's going on - that's probably how this `alarmDate` bug crept in.

**Also** just in case, you know your "alarm receiver" also fires and shows a notification when the device boots and when it first unlocks, right?

Comment: Thanks its really working for me now!

Answer (score 0):

*The (**-2hrs**) above is only correct, when you are in:
(UTC **+1**) zone AND there is SUMMER (**+1**) or
(UTC **+2**) zone AND there is WINTER (**+0**)*

---

The correct datetime is in millis (**kotlin datetime to millisecond convert using local zone and daylight offset**):

```
val myalarmdatetime: String = "2022-05-31 23:59:59"
    
val myalarmdatetimemillis: Long =
        ZonedDateTime.of(
        LocalDateTime.parse(
        myalarmdatetime,
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
        ), ZoneId.systemDefault()
        ).toInstant().toEpochMilli()
```